# How to resize UIDatePicker between two labels

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am trying to get a UIDatePicker to be compatible on multiple devices. I have the labels and everything working, I just want the DatePicker's height to resize depending on the device. Getting it to 'squish' between the labels is the goal. How do I do this?

EDIT: More precise question:
How do I get the UIDatePicker to stay 15 px from both labels and resize itself in order to do this? I want the UIDatePicker to stretch/compress vertically as the device changes. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is also a view only, if you want to adjust the size, at least you can calculate the the date pickers frame. depending on the situation, you can also use constraints.

Comment: I just want it to squish between the two labels using constraints but its so frustrating. Everything's set up, I just want ot be able to say "be 10 away from this label and this label" but it won't resize the view, it tries pushing everything off the screen.

Comment: hmm, if the two label is at left and right of the date picker, you can set the leading and trailing constraint corresponding to the labels. But you also need to constraint the date picker's position and height. for height you can make it fixed height or using ratio to corresponding it to the width. Without more details it is quite hard to give you the solution..

Comment: The date picker is hooked up to the margins, so it fits edge to edge on leading and trailing. Label A is bound to top and Label B is bound to the bottom. They both move up when switching devices, but I don't know how to make the date picker squish its height between them. What other kind of info can I give you? Thank you very much.

Comment: if i am understanding correctly. you have a label attached to top of the screen and a label attached to bottom of the screen, and then you place a date picker between them. I think you just need to set a constraint between datepicker's top to label A's bottom and datepicker's bottom to label B's top. In this way, if the device screen height become smaller, it would automatically make the datepicker shorter.

Comment: When I do that, it pushes the bottom label off the screen.

Comment: you need to make the bottom label attached to superview's bottom and set the bottom label height constraint. In this way you can surely fixed the label position.

Answer (score 0):

`UIStackView` is a perfect way to do this. As far as I've understood you would like to see vertical top and bottom `UILabel`'s and between them `UIPickerView`.

Programatically:

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var verticalStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.addArrangedSubview(leftLabel)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(middlePicker)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(rightsLabel)
        return stack
    }()

    let leftLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Maybe something?"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let rightsLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Maybe something?"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()


    let middlePicker: UIPickerView = {
        let picker = UIPickerView()
        // Some settings
        return picker
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(verticalStackView)

        // Auto layout
        verticalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        verticalStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        verticalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        verticalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // U can manipulate height of both labels, picker view going to be squished by those labels, setting more height of both of them going to make him smaller

        leftLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // 50 height ?
        rightsLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // 50 height ?
    }

}
```

Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without programming? I would really like to fix it with the general layout stuff so I can do it in the future without just copying stuff

Comment: What do u mean by copying ? The programming way is much more clear with giving u the background what exactly is happening behind the stages.

Comment: I would also add that u don't need to set a height constraint for labels, the text inside labels will stretch the content of them. From storyboard way, just add stack with vertical axis and fill distribution, drop label, picker view and label to this and thats it. Put the constraints for stack view to super view as 0 bottom, 0 top, 0 leading, 0 trailing. You can modifie it and play with it